# Jquery .length keeps returning 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to count the section tags on a page but whenever this script runs it returns a 0. Any ideas?

```js
    var sectionCount = $( "section").length;
    console.log(sectionCount);
```

The HTML I'm counting from is as follows:

```html
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <section class="slide">1</section>
            <section class="slide">2</section>
            <section class="slide">3</section>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: when (or where) do you run js script? the `section` elements may not exist if you run the script in the `<head>` when the DOM is not loaded.

Comment: I have the script linked from my document head and its running in its own seperate file. Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/58yuowje/

Comment: If the script is in the head and the `section` elements are in the body, then they don't exist when the script runs.

Comment: It runs BEFORE the rest of the page is loaded. Place the script at the end of the page or run it inside of, for example, `$(document).ready(function() { /* here */; });`

Comment: It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tgp0o87v/)

Comment: @Anubhav, fiddle is running the script on page load change the setting to run in the head of the document.

Comment: [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/cdanea/arqybeob/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `$(document).ready()` clause so that it runs after the html DOM has been loaded.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var sectionCount = $( "section").length;
  console.log(sectionCount);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <section class="slide">1</section>
            <section class="slide">2</section>
            <section class="slide">3</section>
        </div>
    </body>
```